# Help getting started with SQL database on Android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, stocks

I have zero experience with databases, and am looking for some direction in getting started. I am making an Android app that needs to read in a large amount of data quickly... Eventually this will be a stock market app that accesses real-time stock information. But before I spend money trying to get access to such real-time data, I'm working with a Microsoft excel file that has times and information on stocks from the past.

I've read up on databases and apparently Androids come with SQLite but I can't figure out how to start using it, or how to import my excel file.

Please help get me started or point me in the right direction. I've found some tutorials but they were difficult for me to follow with my complete lack of experience, and not necessarily related to my project; I'd need really basic step-by-step instructions...

Comment: Android has SQLite installed; MySQL would require using web services/etc to interact with.

Comment: Thanks!! A step in the right direction. I've edited my question to reflect this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this, think only in terms of data you need, rather than trying to get all spreadsheet data into your SQLite DB.

So, think in terms of learning basic SQL and SQL queries and create the tables (on a piece of paper) you need, how you will manipulate the data in these tables (updates, inserts, deletes etc).

Now that you have the table schema and your queries, the task remains of importing this data into the tables. For this I haven't done this but I am sure you will find a lot of resources on the Internet.

Now, as you can see, the seemingly complicated problem is broken into tangible actionable steps.

[Here](http://zetcode.com/databases/sqlitetutorial/) is a reasonable tutorial on SQLite. [Here](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742) is another for SQLite and Android. You can google for more help.

Also take a look [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/11/migrating-excel-to-sqlite-using-python/). The blog talks about importing from excel into SQLite DB.